# Dynamically aligning pseudo element according to parent height

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create an arrow label, using css `:after`

```css
.one-line {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.one-line:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br></div>
```

I want the after element to take the same height which is of parent, how can I do this by either css or js?

**Note:** The text inside the label is dynamically populating. [Max length of text: **2 lines**]

It might not be possible, as I am thinking, to adjust it any height of parent. Currently I am trying it to adjust for both one and two lines of text.

Comment: this is a good question , because knowing that the :before element isn't a dom element , so can't be access by js ( in order to set border bottom and top = height of div /2 ) . also adding style tag pragmatically work only for one div (in case of multiple div with same class ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `clip-path`. The idea is to use % values in the polygon to only show the needed shape and it will always work whatever the height is:

```css
.one-line {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.one-line:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25px;
  right: -25px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br></div>
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br></div>

<div class="one-line">text</div>

<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></div>
```

Here is another solution that rely on both pseudo elements and some **skew** transformation to create the arrow. You will notice that this one will keep ratio of the arrow.

```css
.one-line {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.one-line:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  right: -25px;
  background: red;
  transform: skewX(20deg) translateX(-33%);
  transform-origin: top;
  z-index: -1;
}

.one-line:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  right: -25px;
  background: red;
  transform: skewX(-20deg) translateX(-33%);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br></div>
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br></div>

<div class="one-line">text</div>

<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></div>
```

Another way with only **one** pseudo element and `linear-gradient`.

```css
.one-line {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.one-line:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  right: -50px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49.4%, red 50%) top, 
   linear-gradient(to top left,    transparent 49.4%, red 50%) bottom;
  background-size:100% 50.2%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br></div>
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br></div>

<div class="one-line">text</div>

<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></div>
```

And finally without any pseudo element and only background on the main element:

```css
.one-line {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left:50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) left/calc(100% - 50px) 100%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49.4%, red 50%) top right/50px 50.2%, 
   linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.4%, red 50%) bottom right/50px 50.2%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br></div>
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br></div>

<div class="one-line">text</div>

<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Temani, you are always a help. I'll look for browser compatibility.

Comment: @bhansa welcome ;)  by the way i guess you will only find issue with IE as usual :)

Comment: @bhansa i added another solution that should be more supported :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could opt to keep the arrow the same size and align it in the middle by changing top to `top: 50%;` and adding `transform: translateY(-50%);`

```css
.one-line{
  
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  
}

.one-line:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid red;
  
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>

<div class="one-line">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have that in mind. I am still trying to achieve the mentioned behavior. Though just for upto two lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

using an svg path as a `background-image`, you could stretch the `background-size` property to `100% 100%`. Just make sure the svg has `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

```
.one-line:after {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 25.1 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25.1 50;" xml:space="preserve"><polygon class="st0" points="0,50 0,50 25,25 0,0" fill="#ff0000"/></svg>');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:100%;
    height: 100%;
   width: 25px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;
    content:'';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7jm54u6L/

Comment: it should be `background-repeat` instead of repeat. By the way great solution

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Edited my response with your fix