# Can this arrow style be accomplished with a variable height?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is a demo of the element that I currently have, styled to have an arrow-like ending pointing to the right:

```css
.label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkred;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  .label:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -.5rem;
    border-top: 1rem solid transparent;
    border-left: .5rem solid darkred;
    border-bottom: 1rem solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<span class="label">
  BREAKING NEWS
</span>

<br><br>

<span class="label">
  BREAKING <br> 
  NEWS
</span>
```

But, since `border-width` doesn't accept percentages, this means I cannot declare the height of that little arrow appendage to be 50% of the height of the element. Instead, I have to declare the borders of that appendage as a specific height (`1rem` in my case). That means that this kind of solution cannot support text spanning through more than 1 line, because the arrow appendage doesn't fit the height of the element anymore.

So, the first usage of it is the look I want, the second one is a showcase of where it goes wrong.

Could the CSS be written to still have that look, but support a variable height?

Comment: another duplicate with more options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289185/8620333

Comment: it's absolutely bonkers how many people have the same problem, and how many solutions were out there, but it was a little tough to find them when it's my first dive into this specific issue, because everyone calls it something else... surely that problem has to have its solution as well.... 

Answer (score 1):

Please run and see the code snippet for the desired result.

```css
.label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkred;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
.label:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -.5rem;
  border-top: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-left: .5rem solid darkred;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*/
.label:before,
.label:after {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.label:before {
  top: 0px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, darkred 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, darkred 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}

.label:after {
  top: 50%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, darkred 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, darkred 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="label">
  BREAKING NEWS
</span>

<br><br>

<span class="label">
  BREAKING <br> 
  NEWS
</span>

<br><br>

<span class="label">
  BREAKING <br> 
  NEWS <br> 
  BREAKING
</span>
```